# How to display array of image from firestore in listview flutter.?

Tags: flutter

I want to display array image from firebase but I get the following errors:

**Errors:**

> Illegal scheme character (at character 13)
> NetworkImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/online-shop-98ea4...
>
> NetworkImage("1", scale: 1.0)
>
> NetworkImage("h", scale: 1.0)

**Code:**

```
 ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              for (int i = 0;
                  i <
                      snapshot.data.documents[index]
                          .data()['images']
                          .length;
                  i++) {
                _listOfImages.add(NetworkImage(
                    snapshot.data.documents[index].data()['images'][i]));
              }
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: CarouselSlider(
                      options: CarouselOptions(),
                      items: _listOfImages
                          .map((item) => Container(
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Image.network(item.toString(),
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000)),
                              ))
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
              // ignore: dead_code
            },
            itemCount: _item.length,
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x;

fetchData(){
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
            .collection("user_category")
            .document(uidCur)
            .collection('categories')
            .getDocuments();
//put your snapshot query here 
       x = querySnapshot.documents;
}
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

         ListView.builder(
         itemCount : x.length;            
          itemBuilder: (context, index)  =>
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: CarouselSlider(
                      options: CarouselOptions(),
                      items: x
                          .map((item) => Container(
                                child: Center(
                                    child: 
                                 Image.network(item.toString(),
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 
                                          1000)),
                              ))
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
              // ignore: dead_code
            },
           
          );
}
```